# How to correctly handle the "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'clear'" when trying to release memory? python related

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, debugging, memory-management

I'm currently backtesting a trading strategy with around 286 trading pairs, and at the end of the loop I'm saving the plots with the backtest results in a particular path before repeating the process with the next trading pair.

The thing is, I realized that my memory available starts increasing as the number of plots saved increases, and that's something that I think can be avoided by releasing the memory properly.

However I tried two different options to do so, but all of them have failed, here's the first option I tried:

```
# Backtesting    
backtest = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80)
backtest.title(f'plt of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair', fontsize = 20)
backtest.rc('xtick', labelsize = 10)
backtest.ylabel('Initial Investment (USDT)', font size=10)
backtest.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period+4:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + df_trading_pair["Return"])), label = "Buy & Hold Strategy")
backtest.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_gross_return)), label = "RSI Strategy")
backtest.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_net_return)), label = "RSI Strategy after fees")
backtest.legend(loc='lower right', font size = "large") 
backtest.savefig(f'C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/Binance API KEY + Binance Wrapper/RSI Backtest/Backtesting of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair.png')
backtest.clear() #release memory
plt.close(backtest) #kill the figure
```

And I got the following output:

> **AttributeError:** 'Figure' object has no attribute 'title'

> **<Figure size 1280x960 with 0 Axes>**

Here's the second option I tried:

```
# Backtesting    
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80)
plt.title(f'plt of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair', fontsize = 20)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize = 10)
plt.ylabel('Initial Investment (USDT)', font size=10)
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period+4:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + df_trading_pair["Return"])), label = "Buy & Hold Strategy")
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_gross_return)), label = "RSI Strategy")
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_net_return)), label = "RSI Strategy after fees")
plt.legend(loc='lower right', font size = "large") 
plt.savefig(f'C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/Binance API KEY + Binance Wrapper/RSI Backtest/Backtesting of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair.png')
plt.clear() #release memory
plt.close() #kill the figure
```

And here's the output I got from that:

> **AttributeError:** module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'clear'

So, I'm lost here. May I get some help to learn how to release my memory properly?

Comment: it's `plt.figure().clear()`

Comment: So, by only changing `plt.clear()` for `plt.figure().clear()` in my second option, will it correctly release the memory? Should I also keep the `plt.close()` as is, or change it for `plt.figure.close()` too?

Comment: that shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the @Jan Wilamouski suggestion, I ended up getting another warning which was the following:

> C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Downloads\Binance futures data\Binance API KEY +
> Binance Wrapper\Massive Backtesting of RSI in a 30m timeframe for any
> crypto paired against USDT on Binance.py:143: RuntimeWarning: More
> than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot
> interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly
> closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see
> the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

So it seems that it wasn't working, and after looking for other suggestions on Google, I ended up changing `plt.figure().clear()` for `plt.clf()` and after that I managed to keep my memory ram fine (around 37%, which was 4% less than before)

## Final solution:

```
# Backtesting    
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12), dpi=80)
plt.title(f'Backtesting of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair', fontsize = 20)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize = 10)
plt.ylabel('Initial Investment (USDT)', fontsize=10)
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period+4:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + df_trading_pair["Return"])), label = "Buy & Hold Strategy")
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_gross_return)), label = "RSI Strategy")
plt.plot(df_trading_days[rsi_period:] ,np.append(100, 100*np.cumprod(1 + RSI_net_return)), label = "RSI Strategy after fees")
plt.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize = "large") 
plt.savefig(f'C:/Users/ResetStoreX/Downloads/Binance futures data/Binance API KEY + Binance Wrapper/RSI Backtest/Backtesting of RSI for the {trading_pair} trading pair.png')
plt.clf() #release memory
plt.close() #kill the figure
```